# WPF C# There is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, wpf

I got trouble handling no row at position 0 any idea how can i fix this?

[image]

MY CODE:

```
public void FillAPModify()
    {
        sqliteConUserData.connection.Close();
        sqliteConUserData.connection.Open();

        var _command = sqliteConUserData.connection.CreateCommand();
        var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM tblTracking Where FileNumber = '" + StaticModel.clickNumValue + "' COLLATE NOCASE");
        string commandText = query;

        var _dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(commandText, sqliteConUserData.connection);

        DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();

        _dataSet.Reset();
        _dataAdapter.Fill(_dataSet);

        _dataTable = _dataSet.Tables[0];
        var rows = _dataTable.Rows;

        string fileNumber = rows[0].ItemArray[0] as string;  \\error
        var shiftDate = rows[0].ItemArray[1];
        var timeCreated = rows[0].ItemArray[2];
        string remarks = rows[0].ItemArray[3] as string;

        UserDataVar = new UserDataProperties
        {
            FileNumber = fileNumber,
            ShiftDate = shiftDate.ToString(),
            TimeCreated = timeCreated.ToString(),
            Remarks = remarks
        };

        sqliteConUserData.connection.Close();
    }
```

I tried this but no wokring:

```
     if (_dataSet.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (_dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               \\my stuff
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is the error, and where did you try putting the check? (And **please** start using parameterized SQL instead of putting values directly into your SQL.)

Comment: Your fix is correct. If you only ever access `rows[0]` inside the innermost `if`, *this* error should not occur anymore. (Clearly, *other* errors might happen due to *other* bugs, but you haven't told us about them yet.)

Comment: The line with the error ` string fileNumber = rows[0].ItemArray[0] as string;` indicates no Rows, eg `_dataTable.Rows` is not populated with data, the query must not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your fix should work, but I always check to make sure the dataset isn't null as well and make it all one if statement.

```
if (_dataSet!= null && _dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    _dataTable = _dataSet.Tables[0];
    var rows = _dataTable.Rows;

    string fileNumber = rows[0].ItemArray[0] as string;  \\error
    var shiftDate = rows[0].ItemArray[1];
    var timeCreated = rows[0].ItemArray[2];
    string remarks = rows[0].ItemArray[3] as string;

    UserDataVar = new UserDataProperties
    {
        FileNumber = fileNumber,
        ShiftDate = shiftDate.ToString(),
        TimeCreated = timeCreated.ToString(),
        Remarks = remarks
    };
}
```

Comment: I disagree here. There is *no way* that `_dataSet` can be `null` in this example: It is initialized to `new DataSet()`, which *never* returns `null` (no `new` class constructor can ever return `null` in C#), and it is never reassigned or passed as a ref parameter. Thus, *if* `_dataSet` is really `null` at that point, there's a hidden bug somewhere and the method *should* fail with an exception (to notify the developer of the bug) instead of just silently doing nothing.

Comment: I cant get the data after that

Comment: Have you thought about making the method return UserDataVar instead of setting it in the method? What happens if the user really has no UserDataProperties?